# Are stereotypes and tropes notable claims?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, notability

There's been more than one question asking about whether a stereotype or a trope correspond to reality.

Example imaginary questions:

- Do African Americans speak in gangsta lingo?
- Do nerds wear black rimmed glasses and calculators?
- Do English people go to work in bowler hats?

It is my understanding that while there's nothing wrong in having questions based on tropes and stereotypes, these questions still need to be otherwise notable.

What is the community's take on it?

Comment: I think these examples suffer from more than just a question of notability, but they suffer from ambiguity.  Unless the question is meant to be "Do a majority of [African Americans, nerds, English people]...", they seem to vague as worded. Of course, I realize they are just imaginary questions, so maybe that's okay...

Answer (score 4):

The guideline, here, is the plausibility of belief (or disbelief).

It's entirely possible that someone believes a call can only be traced [if the caller does not hang up](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/) or even that [an image can be enhanced](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vxq9yj2pVWk). On the other hand, I'm highly skeptical anyone believes that English people go to work wearing bowler hats. It's clearly an exaggeration of reality.

As for all other measures of notability, a Google search is likely to be a good indicator. If you can find several examples of such beliefs taken seriously on, say, Yahoo! Answers then it's notable.

Comment: Agreed. There's an issue though in this case. You will get a *ton* of false positives when googling for examples. For example try [this](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Do+nerds+wear+black+rimmed+glasses+and+calculators%3F)

Comment: @Sklivvz: That is so meta. This page is already the first hit of that search.

Comment: [Obl. XKCD (meta-meta)](http://xkcd.com/978/)